# NIFI Large numbers of workflows configuration and execution strategy

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 14k+ workflows running on NIFI and I observe cluster slowness very often and at times it goes unresponsive. I tried many solutions but sadly cluster restart is the only solution works.

One of the solution that I came across, Leave all workflows in the stopped state and enable only when required then trigger workflow rest. Post execution again change workflow state to stopped state. I yet to implement this solution. I am exploring if there can be any cons of this strategy for large number of workflow? Any other suggestions/best practices to handle huge workflow load would be appreciated.

Note: Currently, my all workflows are scheduled to run daily. We try distribute load on different times.

The reason for slowness is still unknown. When cluster is hang/slow I didn't observe any issues with JVM/CPU/Memory.

Nifi Cluster details:

```
3 nodes, version: HDF: NIFI 1.11.1
 
Processor : 3
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 42
model name : Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge)
stepping : 1
microcode : 0x1
cpu MHz : 3299.998
cache size : 16384 KB
physical id : 3
siblings : 1
core id : 0
cpu cores : 1

Controller Settings:
Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count: 50
Maximum Event Driven Thread Count: 10
```

**Memory**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the size of thread pool in nifi?

Comment: Did you mean config in Controller Settings. If yes I configured- Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count: 50, Maximum Event Driven Thread Count: 10

Comment: Not a lot. However you can try to decrease those nombers. How much memory you set for nifi? What kind of running processors causing an issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Majority of my processors deal with Mysql, Shell Script executor and httpAPI call. I have added memory details to question.

Comment: 60% workflows (9k~ out of 14k )invoke bash script using ExecuteProcess.. do you think that might be an issues?

Comment: i don't see any issue. you have enough memory for nifi. so, probably issue in your scripts. you can control number of parallel executions by `Maximum Thread Count`. also number of parallel executions for each processor. look how memory/cpu used on the level of machine when it's dying.

Comment: thank you for reviewing configuration and suggestions.